# need to setup trace to save ip address of SQL Server login

Tags: sql-server, authentication, ip, trace

What event can I log so I save every login (Windows or User) from within SQL Server name and IP address of where the user is logging in from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to do an actual trace you have two options:

1. Use a server side trace with the Audit Login and Audit Login Failed events.
2. Use an Extended Events session using the Login event.  This has a whole list of fields you can track.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using **[sys.dm_exec_sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-sessions-transact-sql)**:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions;
```

You can use it **Only** for SQL Server 2005 and later.